# after_update calls association's method that depends on the change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

## Intro

I'm having issues with a callback that makes a call to a method on an association, but that method depends on the change that caused the callback. It seems like the association doesn't see change even though it's being called in an `after_update`.

---

## Scenario

A `Nerd` has many `ProblemSet`s and a `ProblemSet` belongs to a `Nerd`

A ProblemSet has a `status` attribute that can be:

- "finding" - finding a problem set to solve
- "solving" - currently solving a problem set
- "solved" - finished solving the problem set

Nerd has a `working` attribute that can be:

- `true` - at least one of the `ProblemSet`s has a status of "solving"
- `false` - none of the `ProblemSet`s have a status of "solving"

---

Here is what the models look like:

```
class ProblemSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :nerd

  after_update :set_nerd_activity
 
  def set_nerd_activity
    if status_changed?
      self.nerd.set_working
    end
  end
end

class Nerd < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :problem_sets

  def set_working
    update_column(:working, solving_a_problem_set?)
  end

  def solving_a_problem_set?
    self.problem_sets.any? do |ps|
      ps.status == "solving"
    end
  end
end
```

---

## The Problem

```
problemSet.status
=> "finding"

problemSet.update(status: "solving")

problemSet.nerd.working
=> false       # I'm expecting this to be true
```

I think the problem is that the `nerd` doesn't see the change, as if the database transaction changing the `ProblemSet's` status is not fully committed when `Nerd#set_status` is called.

My rspec tests for a `Nerd` with one `ProblemSet` don't pass. But they DO work for a `Nerd` with more than one `ProblemSet`.

So I figured maybe it was an rspec thing.

Then I tried it in console and I was still seeing the issue. I was also careful to use `.reload` to check that the values were updated.

I have tried using an `after_commit` and `after_save` instead of `after_update` but that breaks the tests with multiple `ProblemSets` on a nerd.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: when you check the db directly, is it updated?  ( but ActiveRecord didn't pick up the update ) or is the update never done ?

Comment: I don't think so. At least not at the right time. `binding.pry` fires off as expected but the value of `solving_a_problem_set?` is `false` when it should be `true` if the callback actually happens _after_ the _update_ occurs.

Comment: did you test the `status_changed?` condition, then the `update_column`

Comment: (First off, thanks for helping out!) Yes, `status_changed?` is correct. It is calling `set_working` on the associated `nerd`. The problem is when it gets there, `nerd` doesn't see the change supposedly has happened.

Comment: ok try testing this, instead of `problemSet.nerd.working` try `Nerd.find(problemSet.nerd_id).working`

Comment: HM... you know what... I thought I tried that but it looks like it's working now. However my specs are still breaking even though I reload the values. I also tried using `Nerd.find(problemSet.nerd_id)` in the spec but not budging. I could give up on the test or use a worker to set the value later... both ways leave me with the same level of confidence =/

Thanks again for helping me out!

Comment: If this is the case then your fix will in the in the `inverse_of`, I'll add an answer to show u

Comment: Nope, nvm, it's working now. I guess I was just having object caching issues. Add an answer and I'll give you the points ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way should be working, the answer I supplied in the comment worked because you were querying for the object outside the relation, this should make it work on the old code you had.

```
class ProblemSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :nerd, inverse_of: :problem_sets
end

class Nerd < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :problem_sets, inverse_of: :nerd
end
```